# Import database in creating docker container - need use pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, docker

Has someone solved the **postgre database auto import** when creating a **docker image**? The traditional method is to put files into the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. But, it does not work for me, because I need to import via `pg_restore` (because of custom-format dump). I do not know how to start **postgres service** through **dockerfile**. The problem is that every time it  runs in a separate container layer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by put .sh script(which contains pg_restore commands) to docker-entrypoint-inidb.d. I use official Postgre image, which runs after dockerfile any .sql and .sh files, which are in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
More info https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#how-to-extend-this-image